# Express entry profile doesn't ask for spouse information

Tags: immigration, canada, resident-permit, family, express-entry

I just created my express entry profile and in there I wasn't asked about my spouse's degree, IELTS results and working experience. It just asked if I'm married and then how much money I'd bring. Where do I specify spouse's language scores and degree information? I believe these impact my scores. Therefore I was expecting that the profile would ask for these information somewhere. But I didn't come across them.

Comment: Why do you believe your spouse's information impacts your score?